# Re-write Async JS process (Possibly to use JQuery Promise)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred, web-sql

I am having trouble with two functions because they rely on chaining Async Tasks. The `clearAll` is a click event which should empty the database then reload the page.  `Clear` is a function from the database module (`database.clear`).

I would like to use JQuery Promises/Deffered if they are appropriate but I cant quite grasp them for this use case.

I have re-written the code following @Larry K's answer

```
    clearAll: function()
    {
        var refresh = function()
        {
            localStorage.clear();  
            sessionStorage.clear();
            window.location.href = window.location.pathname;
            console.log("feeling refreshed");
        };

        database.open();

                    //This is what I'd like to be able to do
                    //With Jquery or callbacks
        $.when(database.clear()).then(refresh);

    },

clear: function (callback, errorCallback)
{
    var sql = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name != ?",
    args = ["__WebKitDatabaseInfoTable__"];

    var dbTableNamesResult = function (tx, result)
    {
       var dropSql  = "";

       for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++)
       {
        dropSql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + result.rows.item(i).name + "; ";
        execute(dropSql);
       }
    };

    execute(sql, args, dbTableNamesResult);
},
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/caolan/async if you have a lot of async flows. Makes the world a happy place.

Comment: @Ekin I do have a lot of asnyc flows and async.js looks like it might be the ticket.  But before I re-write a whole load of code, could you show me how the above would be executed in Async.js?  I'm giving it a go as we speak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having attempted to implement jQuery deferred myself the answer I was looking for was provided by zerkms's answer to *[How can I write this as a jQuery deffered function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615254)*

Answer (score 0):

The big issue is that you have two layers of callbacks including a loop for the second layer.

You're using the db to queue multiple `drop table` calls since you're immediately calling many `database.dropTable` methods (without waiting for the prior one to complete.)

That's fine but an easier way to solve the problem is to drop all of the tables at once. The [SQLite manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) says that multiple table drop sql statements are supported. But you'd probably want to test it.

It appears that you're using a wrapper library around the sql calls, yes? Use the appropriate call for the execSQL method shown in my code.

Also, your refresh function is being called both for success and failure of the drop table statement. AFAIK, you're never going to call your `errorCallback`. I'd try:

```
var clearDatabase = function (successCallback, errorCallback) {
  var dbTableNamesResult = function (tx, result) {          
        var sql1 = '',
            rows = result.rows;

        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          sql1 = sql1 + " DROP TABLE " + rows.item(i).name + ";";
        }

        //now make one call to drop multiple tables...
        database.execSQL(sql1, successCallback, errorCallback);
           // pseudo function, update as appropriate
      }

  database.open();
  database.query(
    "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name != ?",
    ['__WebKitDatabaseInfoTable__'], dbTableNamesResult);
};
```

**added**

The function which calls clearDatabase should provide both the successCallback and  errorCallback. In case of error, either try again or just log it...

**updated**

I see that that the successCallback and errorCallback functions can be called directly by the db. Updated the code.

**Resources used in this answer**

HTML5 Rocks: [Client-Side Storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/)

[Getting Started with HTML5 Local Databases](http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/)

SQLite [SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html)

Comment: Hi Larry, I don't really see much difference in your code to mine.  the clear database function should only execute its succesCallback when all the tables have been dropped.  Your snippet would execute the successCallback on each dropped table.  Though to drop them all at once would obviously circumnavigate this.

Comment: Oops, I didn't close the loop properly. The idea is ONE sql execute with the multi_statement "Drop table foo; Drop table bar;" etc. Thus one success or failure callback. Also note that my version is shorter than the original.

Comment: It was a good idea @Larry but unfortunately it doesn't appear to work with multiple commands "DROP TABLE foo; DROP TABLE bar";

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for checking it out.