# How can I write this as a jQuery deffered function

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred, web-sql

I need to get ALL the tables in the database and then I delete them one by one. However each `DROP TABLE` is asnyc. **Most importantly** the returned promise should only be resolved when all the tables have been dropped.

```
clear: function() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var sql = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name != ?",
    args = ["__WebKitDatabaseInfoTable__"];

    var dbTableNamesResult = function(tx, result) {
        var dropSql = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
            dropSql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + result.rows.item(i).name + "; ";
            execute(dropSql, null, errorCallback);
        }
    };

    execute(sql, args, dbTableNamesResult, dfd.reject);
    return dfd;
},
```

`Execute` takes four parameters, `sql`, `arguments`, `successCallback` and `errorCallback`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
clear: function() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var sql = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name != ?",
    args = ["__WebKitDatabaseInfoTable__"];

    dfd.pipe(function(tx, result) {
        var deferreds = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            dropSql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + result.rows.item(i).name + "; ";
            execute(dropSql, dfd.resolve, errorCallback);
            deferreds.push(dfd);
        }

        return $.when.apply(null, deferreds);
    });

    execute(sql, args, dfd.resolve, dfd.reject);
    return dfd;
},
```

Here is a similar example http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/XQwPq/

```
function getTables()
{
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: {
            json: '{"tables":["a","b","c"]}',
            delay: 1
        },
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            dfd.resolve(response.tables);             
        }
    });

    return dfd;
}

function dropTables(tables)
{
    console.log('tables to delete: ' + tables.join(', '));

    var deferreds = [];

    for (var i = 0, len = tables.length; i < len; i++) {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        (function(dfd) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/echo/json/',
                data: {
                    json: '{"table":"' + tables[i] + '"}',
                    delay: Math.random() * 3
                },
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log('table ' + response.table + ' deleted');
                    dfd.resolve();             
                }
            });
        })(dfd);

        deferreds.push(dfd);
    }

    return $.when.apply(null, deferreds);
}

getTables().pipe(dropTables).done(function() {
    console.log('process finished');
});
​
```

Description: first function `getTables` returns deferred object with result of ajax request. We pipe another function `dropTables` with it and create in it another deferred object, that will accept N deferreds to its `when`. And as long as they are resolved - final anonymous with `process finished` is shown

Comment: I have no idea what that does, but I will look it up and give it a test! I have never seen "$.when.apply" before.  the execute in the for loop, should that be dfd.reject?

Comment: @CrimsonChin: nope. Give me a second to compose some jsfiddle example

Comment: works a charm and thank you! even more so for the example.  I would never have even dreamed that up

Comment: Ok, wouldnt it make sense to reject the original deferred obj if there was an error whilst dropping the tables?

Comment: @CrimsonChin: here is a demonstration of what would happen http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/XQwPq/1/. And it depends on what you want to achieve